# how can I make an array that each element of is a random image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I want to make an array in python that has about 40000 elements and each element is a random image with size 28x28. I use this code but it produces the following error. I am a beginner in python.

```
    wtrain=np.zeros((40000,28,28,1))
    for i in range(40000):
        w_main = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4,1))
        w_main=w_main.astype(np.float32)
        w_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28,1),dtype='float32')
        w_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_main
        w_expand.reshape(1,28,28,1)
        wtrain[i,:,:,:]=w_expand
```

the error

> All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array
>   shapes: [(49999, 28, 28, 1), (1, 28, 28, 1)]

what is the problem? how can I add these random images to wtrain? Thanks

I change my code to this:

```
wtrain=[]
for i in range(2):
    w_main = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4,1))
    w_main=w_main.astype(np.float32)
    w_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28,1),dtype='float32')
    w_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_main
    w_expand.reshape(1,28,28,1)
    wtrain.append(w_expand)
```

Comment: Use the `size` parameter? `numpy.random.randint(0, 255, size=(40000,28,28))` OR `numpy.random.random(size=(40000,28,28) * scalar`.

Comment: Thank you. I want to send them as an input to cnn, so I should change the shape from (40000,28,28) to (40000,28,28,1)? if yes, can I do it with reshape?

Comment: but this code produce a random image with size 28x28.but if you see my code I want to have a 28x28 image that only a 4x4 segment of it is random and all other parts are 0. could you please tell me how can I do this? due to this I write the code with for.

Comment: I changed my code and put it above. is it true? because I could not see each element of the array. I used this plt.imshow(wtrain[0,:,:,1]) but it produced this error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: could you please help me, because I cannot find suitable things on google and I really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `zeros` array of the required shape - I used (3,7,7) instead of your (40000,28,28).

```
a = np.zeros((3,7,7))
```

Make an array of random numbers with a shape of your spec - the first dimension size is the same as the `zeros` array

```
b = np.random.randint(0,255, size=(3,4,4))
```

Assign the random values to the zeros array using indexing on the left-hand-side of the assignment to put those values where you want

```
a[:,:4,:4] = b
```

Result

```
In [20]: a[0,...]
Out[20]: 
array([[ 241.,  228.,  176.,  194.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 185.,  240.,  219.,  175.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 206.,   82.,   32.,  137.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [  58.,  181.,  242.,  168.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]])

In [21]: a[1,...]
Out[21]: 
array([[  25.,   19.,  251.,   89.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 204.,   25.,   72.,  176.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 189.,   37.,   33.,   49.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [  72.,  168.,   68.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]])

In [22]: a[2,...]
Out[22]: 
array([[  74.,  228.,  186.,  133.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 147.,   83.,  194.,  205.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [  34.,  185.,   21.,    6.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [  14.,  245.,   46.,  154.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]])
```

Add another dimension by reshaping

```
In [26]: x,y,z = a.shape

In [27]: c = a.reshape((x,y,z,1))

In [28]: c.shape
Out[28]: (3, 7, 7, 1)
```

Comment: excellent. Thank you. working with python is fantastic. sorry, if I want to imshow each element of c as 7x7 image how can I do it?

Comment: [Iterating](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html) over the first dimension will produce *individual* images with shape (7,7,1) so you would probably need to reshape them to (7,7) before actually using them as an image.